# How to find which character set is used by the database

Tags: character-encoding, sap-ase

I can access the database either from a .NET program (using ODBC) or through a database management tool (written in Java).

If I write a 'é' character to the database from the .NET program, it appears as 'Õ' (capital O with tilde) in the DB management tool.

If I write a 'é' character to the database from the DB management tool, it appears as 'Å' (capital A with a circle on top) in the .NET program.

I am not trying to actually solve the problem (i.e. having both programs show the same thing), although that would be nice. I am merely trying to guess which character sets each is using to interpret the data, so that I can do the conversion myself if I dump data using .NET and re-input it using the tool.

So, which combination of 2 character sets would give the character mismatches described above?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** using Sybase ASE 12.5

**EDIT:** basically the question is: do you know of a character encoding whose E9 code point represents character 'Õ' (capital O with tilde) or 'Å' (capital A with a circle on top)? (this supposes one of them is using Latin 1, hence the E9, which I think is pretty likely)

**EDIT:** Paul's solution does it. The answer about the charset is: [hp-roman8](http://www.kostis.net/charsets/hproman8.htm)

Comment: Can you tell us which DBMS you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sybase automatically tries to do a conversion if there are different charactersets being used on the server and the client. If you turn the automatic charset conversion off using,

```
set char_convert off
```

do you still get the same 'Õ' and 'Å''s?

Comment: Brilliant! it worked! I'm still curious as to what on earth sybase thought it was converting the text to, but that solves the problem! Thanks!